# Calling printf by MASM

Tags: masm

I am trying to explore world of assembly :) But for some reason, it does not work :( It compiles, but at running, it prints out nothing :(

```
.386
.model flat,stdcall
option casemap:none
include \masm32\include\windows.inc
include \masm32\include\kernel32.inc
includelib \masm32\lib\kernel32.lib
include \masm32\include\user32.inc
includelib \masm32\lib\user32.lib
includelib \masm32\lib\msvcrt.lib ; Some default includes :P

printf proto C :vararg

.data
Text       db "Hello World",0

.code
start:
mov eax, offset Text
push eax ; Push text to the stack
call printf 
pop eax ; Pop text from the stack
push 0 ; Exit code 0 (Success)
call ExitProcess
end start
```

Comment: Works for me. How exactly did you build and run it?

Comment: @Michael Built it using masm32 sdk. Commands:
C:\masm32\bin>ml.exe /c /coff test.asm
C:\masm32\bin>link.exe /subsystem:windows test.obj

Comment: This seems to be a console application, so you should use `/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE` when linking. If you insist on building a windowed application you'll have to explicitly create a console to print to.

Comment: @Michael Oh thank you :) You could write an answer, and I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to link with `/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE` for your current code to print anything.

From [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/subsystem-specify-subsystem?view=vs-2019) for `SUBSYSTEM`:

> `WINDOWS`
> Application does not require a console, probably because it creates its own windows for interaction with the user.
>
> `CONSOLE`
> Win32 character-mode application. The operating system provides a console for console applications.